# Converting List in the dataframe to dataframe columns

Tags: python

I had a Dataframe as below

```
date             bumpSizes
12/9/23            ['-0.2','-0.4','0.8']
12/9/23             ['-0.2, '-0.3']
```

need to convert the bumpSize from list to columns like below (unique values)

```
index           bumpSizes
12/9/23           -0.2
12/9/23           -0.4
12/9/23            0.8
12/9/23           -0.3
```

I tried the below options

```
    df["bumpSizes"]=df["bumpSizes"].str.replace("'","").str.replace ("[","").str.replace ("]","")
    df= df[index].str.split(",", expand=True)
```

But this is expanding into rows instead of columns.

Also tried

```
df.assign("bump_new",df.bumpSizes)
```

But this also printing in rows.

Please let me know how to convert the list values into columns with same column name.

Comment: You want to remove duplicates as well?

Comment: Yes.Need to remove duplicates too..

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data= {'date':['12/9/23', '12/9/23'],
'bumpSizes': [['-0.2', '-0.4', '0.8'], ['-0.2', '-0.3']]}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()
```

Output-

```
      date          bumpSizes
0  12/9/23  [-0.2, -0.4, 0.8]
1  12/9/23       [-0.2, -0.3]
```

you can use the `explode` function in pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

```
df = df.explode('bumpSizes')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='bumpSizes')
df.head()
```

Output-

```
      date bumpSizes
0  12/9/23      -0.2
0  12/9/23      -0.4
0  12/9/23       0.8
1  12/9/23      -0.3
```

If you want to change the index, you can do `df.set_index('date',inplace=True)`

Comment: Getting this error..  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'.  I have created the dataframe using pd.read_csv

Comment: Can you post the `error` message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/1586944/git/risk-etl/script/test4.py", line 20, in <module>
    df = df.explode('bumpSizes')
  File "C:\Users\1586944\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5067, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: that's strange,  `Error message` shouldn't come unless you are using `older` version of `pandas`. As you can see in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)  `pandas.DataFrame` has explode function

Comment: Using python 3.7. Pandas 0.24.2

Comment: Pandas version is 0.24.2

Comment: Update your `pandas`,  you are using very old version of pandas,  Current stable version is `2.1.0`, that is the reason you are getting `attribute error`.

Comment: Updated the version of pandas. Now explode works..But till not converting to columns..                                                                                                                                                   
 df = df[["asOfDate","bumpSizes"]]
    print("Before DF")
    print(df)
    df = df.explode("bumpSizes")
    df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='bumpSizes')
    print("After DF")
    print(df.head())
    df.to_csv("output/df.csv",index=False)

Comment: Output: Before DF
     asOfDate                                          bumpSizes
0  2023-08-03  ['-0.1', '-0.09', '-0.08', '-0.07', '-0.06', '...
After DF
     asOfDate                                          bumpSizes
0  2023-08-03  ['-0.1', '-0.09', '-0.08', '-0.07', '-0.06', '...